# ¿Porque no puedo ver los layouts en android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Estoy empezando a trabajar con android studio 3, pero a la hora de abrir el layout me manda el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El layout se queda cargando pero no muestra nada.

Comment: Publica el xml donde te lanza el error.

Comment: Android studio 3 según los reportes presenta varios problemas, es recomendable no actualizar aun.